# Серийный номер и imei

Tags: поиск, imei, устройства

Возможно ли найти серийный номер устройства по imei , связаны ли они каким-то образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Оба этих понятия так или иначе идентифицируют устройство, но между
>   собой не связаны.

На самом деле получить серийный номер устройства по imei можно. Но для этого нужно иметь доступ к базе данных производителя телефонов. Каждому производителю телефонов выделяется пул номеров imei. А при производстве при записи в телефон номера imei телефону дополнительно присваивается серийный номер. Вся эта информация хранится в базе данных производства. К сожалению (а может быть к счастью) обычно эти базы данных недоступны для внешних пользователей. Но эти базы существуют и они доступны (например) по запросу правоохранительных органов.

Некоторые производители имеют на своих сайтах формы ввода по которым можно зарегистрировать купленное устройство. В качестве кода регистрации можно вводить либо серийный номер либо тип устройства. Такие формы я видел например на сайте Тошиба для телевизоров. Не знаю, есть ли такие формы на сайтах производителей телефонов. Но вполне возможно что есть или что такие формы будут сделаны. Может быть тогда появится возможность получить серийный номер устройства по imei.

Answer (score 3):

IMEI (англ. International Mobile Equipment Identity  — международный идентификатор мобильного оборудования) — это номер, обычно уникальный, для идентификации телефонов GSM, WCDMA и IDEN, а также некоторых спутниковых телефонов. Имеет 15 цифр в десятичном представлении, где последняя цифра контрольная по алгоритму Луна, либо 17, где ещё две цифры - это версия.

Серийный номер — уникальный идентификатор, который присваивается выпущенному продукту производителем, что позволяет распознать конкретный продукт и отличать его от других единиц. Серийный номер обычно состоит преимущественно из цифр, в некоторых случаях используются и буквы. Часто сопровождается пометкой «S/N» (англ. Serial Number).

Если проще:
IMEI - это номер, по которому друг от друга отличают GSM(WCDMA, IDEN) модули. Он у всех устройств имеет одинаковый стандарт и форму.
  Серийный же номер - это код устройства, который добавляется производителем на заводе.
Оба этих понятия так или иначе идентифицируют устройство, но между собой не связаны.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что связку Серийный номер - Imei ты не сможешь выцепить, по IMEI максимум можно бренд, модель и спецификацию устройства получить.

Посмотри https://imeidb.xyz к примеру. Или https://imei.info